# Opening multiple finder directories simultaneously

Tags: mac, finder, folders

Is there a way to open multiple finder directories at the same time without necessarily opening two windows? I'm thinking something similar to opening multiple tabs in a mac terminal.

Comment: Never mind. I just figured out. For those wondering, all I had to do was press Cmd T. This makes navigation much easier.